# Can I call a function inside a function solidity?

Tags: function, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a function in my contract that take 2 numbers and give a random number between those 2.
Can I call this function inside some others functions in the same contract?

Something like:

```
function point(min, max) public view returns (uint256) {
    return /* A number betwwen "min" and "max" */;
}

function generateSVG() public pure returns (string memory) {
   .
   .
   .
    svg = string(abi.encodePacked(svg, "stroke-width='" , point(1, 5) , "' "));
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: sometimes.

Long answer:

In solidity, we specify the visibility of functions and state variables. There are 4 types of visibility:

- Internal
- External
- Public
- Private

Unless defined explicitly, visibility defaults to `internal`.

### Internal

A function/state variable is only visible to contracts that contains it, or inherits a contract that contains it

### External

Can only be called by other contracts

### Public

Any contract, whether it contains the code or not, can call

### Private

Only the contract that declares it can call, not the ones that inherit it.

### Beware, regarding randomness

There is no true randomness in ethereum. You can either create pseudo-random values with blockhash/block height or you can use an oracle that provides true randomness, like [Chainlik](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-a-random-number/)

Comment: "pseudo-random values with blockhash/block height" do you mean something like:
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, block.difficulty, msg.sender)) ??

Comment: Yeap can be. But keep in mind that people can predict that value

Comment: I'm new on Blockchain, I'm trying to make a NFT Art Collection with random SVG, 
if I understand correctly, nodes can predict this Random Number, and with that predict what the entire collection would be like. But they can't access the balance sheet, or upgrade the contract in any way, right? Thank you for the patience.

Comment: I think you need to ask another question for that, it is not in the scope of this question

Comment: How do I upvote ? Im new here.
I tried the up arrow, but:
"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 <a href="/help/whats-reputation">reputation</a> to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can call it will work unless you defined it as either public or private(in case you want to call the function within the same contract and restrict to inherited contracts) or internal. an example is shown below.

`// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

contract FunctionCall {

```
uint public addition = add(1,2);
uint public product = multiply(add(2,3),add(2,1));

function add(uint a,uint b)public pure returns(uint output){
    output = a+b;
}

function multiply(uint a,uint b)public pure returns(uint){
    return a*b;
}
```

}
`